# How do I redirect a domain?

Tags: proxy

I have a php file in my PC, I want the app in my iPhone to access this file! like the app should be redirected to PC with that PHP code, anyone know how to do this? with XAMPP?? I don't know anything about how to configure this, I'm a newbie :/

Answer (score 0):

You're 'hosting' the PHP file on XAMPP. All you have to do is type in the local IP (or your public IP if you want to access it from mobile phone internet (no wlan) and ports open) and you're already there.

Start > cmd.exe > ipconfig

There you usually find your local IP and Public IP.

Incase you have a domain: Add a A-Record

Comment: How do I configure XAMPP to redirect the app in the iPhone to access the php file? how does the iPhone app know in which location the php file is? should I point the location of the file in XAMPP settings? how to do it? please explain it like I'm noob :P :/